# jquery changing background picture of div on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 10 small pictures across the bottom of the screen and one main picture. What I am trying to achieve is having the main picture replaced by one of the 10 small pictures, when they are clicked on.

Code so far is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#sp<?php echo $i; ?>').on {
        'click', (function () {
            $('#product-detail-pic').css('background-image', 'url(images/stock/<?php echo $stock[1][pic.$i]; ?>');
        });
    }
);
```

and the HTML/PHP is

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {
    if(($stock[1]['pic'.$i]!='')) { ?>
        <div id="sp<?php echo $i; ?>" style="padding-right:13px; width:84px;    height:61px; background:url(images/stock/<?php echo $stock[1]['pic'.$i]; ?>) no-repeat;float:left; background-size:84px 61px;">
            <img src="images/zoom.png" width="40" height="30" />
        </div>                      
<?php }
```

Comment: in case it is not a copy-paste error, the closing bracket in your function is wrong, it should be `};` instead of `);`.

Comment: $('#sp<?php echo $i; ?>').on{'click', (function() { how do you set up values of $i, there must be php loop to bind click action on all 10 small images, if i were you i would use class and bind click on class not individual id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend doing it this way as you need to bind the event handlers on each thumbnail, and that's not efficient.
It's better if you put the thumbnail ID on the HTML tag instead of binding the click event on each thumbnail.

Your PHP code should look like this:

```
<?php
for( $i=1; $i<6; $i++ ) {
    if( $stock[1]['pic'.$i] != '' ) { ?>
        <div data-img-url="<?php echo $stock[1]['pic'.$i] ?>" style="padding-right:13px; width:84px; height:61px; background:url(images/stock/<?php echo $stock[1]['pic'.$i]; ?>) no-repeat;float:left; background-size:84px 61px;">
            <img src="images/zoom.png" width="40" height="30" />
        </div>
    }
}
?>
```

and your jQuery event handler should look something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $( '[data-img-url]' ).on( 'click', function () {
        $('#product-detail-pic').css('background-image', $( this ).data( 'img-url' ) );
    });
});
```

No messing with PHP on the JS side, much cleaner and efficient :)

I'm using `'[data-img-url]'` as a jQuery selector just for this example. On your site, you should be using a selector that's relevant to the thumbnails.

For example, if your thumbnails are placed in a container with the `thumbnails` ID, then you could do:

```
$( "#thumbnails" ).on( 'click', '[data-img-url]', function() {
    $('#product-detail-pic').css('background-image', $( this ).data( 'img-url' ) );
} );
```

Comment: Elegant answer, now if I could only get it to work! When anyone of the small thumbnails is clicked, I need it to swap it's background image with the main image on the page. I know the logic is correct, just down to the syntax now.

Comment: Actually the code above should just work if you change the selectors. If your thumbnails are placed in a #thumbnails div, then the second example above should work. Please update the image paths also, I forgot putting the images/stock path on the PHP code :)

Comment: I have added a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Run57/) if you can see where it is wrong, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It's really confusing for users if you swap the clicked thumbnail with the previously active image. I suggest to just mark the current active thumbnail with a border or something. Here's the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GkZQ4/

Answer (score 2):

You are missing qoutes in `$stock[1][pic.$i]` chnage like this,

```
$('#product-detail-pic').css('background-image','url(images/stock/<?php echo $stock[1]['pic'.$i]; ?>');
```

Comment: Bad cut and paste, quotes were missing and functions werent closed off properly. fixed all that but still no joy....

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
var imgId = '<?php echo $stock[1]["pic".$i]; ?>';
$('#product-detail-pic').css('background-image','url(images/stock/'+imgId+')');
```